# Extend WP Customizer to make multiple image selection possible

Tags: custom-field, images, uploads

**Is there a way to extend the Wordpress Customizer, in order to enable multiple selections?**

This looks like what I want:
https://github.com/lucatume/multi-image-control. I don't get it to work. It only shows `add` button and `remove` button but they don't do anything.

Is there another existing extension script that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I eventually did was **extending the `WP_Customize_Control`** class as follows:

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('WP_Customize_Image_Control')) {
    return null;
}

class Multi_Image_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control
{
    public function enqueue()
    {
      wp_enqueue_style('multi-image-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/multi-image.css');
      wp_enqueue_script('multi-image-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/multi-image.js', array( 'jquery' ), rand(), true);
    }

    public function render_content()
    { ?>
          <label>
            <span class='customize-control-title'>Image</span>
          </label>
          <div>
            <ul class='images'></ul>
          </div>
          <div class='actions'>
            <a class="button-secondary upload">Add</a>
          </div>

          <input class="wp-editor-area" id="images-input" type="hidden" <?php $this->link(); ?>>
      <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I use javascript to open the WP media selector when the user clicks on 'Add'. When an image is selected, the image must appear inside `<ul class='images'></ul>`. Furthermore the user needs to be able to remove an image by clicking on an image. I made the following **javascript file**:

```
( function( $ ) {

        $(window).load(function(){
            var begin_attachment_string = $("#images-input").val();
            var begin_attachment_array = begin_attachment_string.split(",");
            for(var i = 0; i < begin_attachment_array.length; i++){
                if(begin_attachment_array[i] != ""){
                    $(".images").append( "<li class='image-list'><img src='"+begin_attachment_array[i]+"'></li>" );
                }
            }
            $(".button-secondary.upload").click(function(){
                var custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    multiple: true
                });

                custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
                    var selection = custom_uploader.state().get('selection');
                    var attachments = [];
                    selection.map( function( attachment ) {
                        attachment = attachment.toJSON();
                        $(".images").append( "<li class='image-list'><img src='"+attachment.url+"'></li>" );
                        attachments.push(attachment.url);
                        //
                     });
                     var attachment_string = attachments.join() + "," + $('#images-input').val();
                     $('#images-input').val(attachment_string).trigger('change');
                 });
                 custom_uploader.open();
             });

             $(".images").click(function(){
                 var img_src = $(event.target).find("img").attr('src');
                 $(event.target).closest("li").remove();
                 var attachment_string = $('#images-input').val();
                 attachment_string = attachment_string.replace(img_src+",", "");
                 $('#images-input').val(attachment_string).trigger('change');
             });
         });

} )( jQuery );
```

At last, I added **some CSS**:

```
.image-list{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image-list:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff, inset 0 0 0 5px #c60c31;
}
.image-list:hover:before{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Tom Groot

Comment: For Firefox support, i've just had to replace the `$(window).load` with `$(window).ready` callback, otherwise the currently configured images won't show up

Answer (score 0):

@tom-groot this worked for me, but I tweaked it a few ways. This saves ids instead of the full url, removes the trailing comma, and avoids using "event" since it's deprecated.

Javascript:

```
  "use strict";
  $(window).load(function () {
    /*
    * Show photos on load
    */
    var begin_attachment_string = $("#images-input").val();
    var begin_attachment_array = begin_attachment_string.split(",");

    // get all attachments
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < begin_attachment_array.length; i++) {
      var id = begin_attachment_array[i];
      if (id != "") {
        promises[i] = wp.media.attachment(id).fetch();
      }
    }
    // wait until they all finish since it's async
    Promise.all(promises)
    // add the images into the dom
    .then(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < begin_attachment_array.length; i++) {
        var id = begin_attachment_array[i];
        if (begin_attachment_array[i] != "") {
          $(".images").append(
            "<li class='image-list'><img src='" +
              wp.media.attachment(id).get("url") +
              "' data-id='" +
              id +
              "'></li>"
          );
        }
      }
    })


    /*
    * Add Photos
    */
    $(".button-secondary.upload").click(function () {
      var custom_uploader = (wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        multiple: true,
      }));

      custom_uploader.on("select", function () {
        var selection = custom_uploader.state().get("selection");
        var attachments = [];
        selection.map(function (attachment) {
          attachment = attachment.toJSON();
          $(".images").append(
            "<li class='image-list'><img src='" +
              attachment.url +
              "' data-id='" +
              attachment.id +
              "'></li>"
          );
          attachments.push(attachment.id);
        });
        var previous = $("#images-input").val() ? "," + $("#images-input").val() : ""; // get rid of trailing commas
        var attachment_string = attachments.join() + previous;
        $("#images-input").val(attachment_string).trigger("change");
      });
      custom_uploader.open();
    });


    /*
    * Remove images when you click on an image
    */
    $(".images").click(function (e) {
      var img_id = $(e.target).find("img").attr("data-id");
      $(e.target).closest("li").remove();
      var attachment_string = $("#images-input").val();
      attachment_string = attachment_string.replace(img_id, "");
      attachment_string = attachment_string.replaceAll(",,", ","); // get rid of duplicate commas
      attachment_string = attachment_string.replace(/^,+|,+$/g, ""); // get rid of leading or trailing commans
      $("#images-input").val(attachment_string).trigger("change");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The php to call it:

````
function register_customize_sections( $wp_customize ) {
 
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'image_selector_section', array(
       'title'=> __( 'Image Selector Section', 'TextDomain' ),
       'priority' => 201
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 
        'multi_image_selector', 
        array(
            'default'   => array(),
            'transport' => 'refresh',
        ) 
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new Multi_Image_Custom_Control (
        $wp_customize,
        'multi_image_selector',
        array(
            'description' => 'Select One or Multiple Images',
            'section'  => 'image_selector_section',
        )
    ) );
}
add_action('customize_register', 'register_customize_sections');```
````